# Can I start with a spring boot application without the annotations componentscan,autoconfiguration,configuration,springbootapplication?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have written some code in order test integration with mongoDB. Please find the link to the main method for running this spring boot application below,

https://github.com/siva54/simpleusercontrol/blob/master/src/main/java/com/siva/UserManagementApplication.java

From what I have read, An application should contain any of the configurations from the following URL to declare how the applications manages the context,

http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html

I haven't used any of those contexts, However my application works fine and I'm able to run it without any issues. Am I missing something here? Can you please help with the info of how my application is able to start and manage the context/dependencies automatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`@SpringBootApplication` is equivalent of `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`. Let's consider why your application works without of any of this three annotations.

**Why it works without `@Configuration`:**

When Spring will scan packages, it will find all classes marked by `@Configuration` and will use them as part of configuration. But in next line you manually passed `UserManagementApplication` as configuration source:

```
SpringApplication.run(UserManagementApplication.class, args);
```

So spring doesn't need to find this class by scan. Therefor it is not necessary to mark it by `@Configuration`.

---

**Why it works without `@ComponentScan`:**

Class `UserManagementApplication` has `@ImportResource("classpath:spring/application-context.xml")` annotation. That means file `spring/application-context.xml` will be included into configuration. And this file contains next line:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.siva.*" />
```

So, you don't need use annotation for scan packages, because you already declared it in the xml file.

---

**Why it works without `@EnableAutoConfiguration`:**

This annotation allows to Spring to try guess and configure the components automatically. For example, if you include the following dependency in your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb'
}
```

Spring configures all the components required to work with MongoDB automatically. And all you need just specify host and user/pass in the `aplication.proprties` file.

But you preferred to declare all needed beans manually in the `spring/application-context.xml` file. So, you simply don't need `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotation at all.